# Google-cast: Unable to white list app. Missing option for "Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for updates"

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

[image]

This is a screenshot from my Mac's Chromecast app. As you can see the options to tick the "Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for updates" is missing. I have another Chromecast device on the same wifi network and for that device the option is present.
Doen anybody know why that option is gone and how I can get it back? I need it to white list the device so that I can develop apps for it.

Comment: Since this is not a coding question, I suggest you contact https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?rd=1 to get direct help on this.

Comment: I did that and this is the answer: "Thank you for contacting Google Cast Developer Support. That 'second' check box is being deprecated and going forward the device ID will be automatically sent to us to ensure any active devices receive the most current builds.".